# intraweb align region in a template

Tags: templates, alignment, region, intraweb

There is a template (Header, Body, footer - sized by CSS with "-ms-flex").
Without knowing top and height of body, how can I force a IWRegion to fit in the Body.
I simply tried:

```
<body>
{%IWRegion1%}
</body>
```

and set the control IWRegion1 to Align=alClient.
But this didn't work. The IWRegion1 is showing with it's absolute width and not aligning to browser width.

In general, when using templates with intraweb any settings of "Anchors" and "Align" don't work.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Once you are using templates, IntraWeb does not use its own JavaScript runtime to control elements alignment. It has to be done using CSS or your own JavaScript.